# How to remove tooltip generated by hover in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used hover to display tooltip on hover. However the text keeps getting appended because the function I have written on mouseout is not working.

Below is my code:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j("#choice30QID404").hover(
function () {
   // $j(this).append($("<span> HOVERING!!!!! </span>"));
    $j(this).append("<span>HOVERING!!!!!</span>");
});              

$j("#choice30QID404").click(function() {
  $j(this).mouseout();
});
```

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem and show your (minimal) HTML to which this jQuery should apply?

Comment: Where is your `mouseout` handler? Also, you can write functions for both `mouseover` and `mouseout` within `hover`.

Comment: `.mouseout()` isn't a function to remove an element, I think. Dig the api deeper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this simply using title attribute. Unless and until you don't want to customize. I am writing without noConflict()

```
$('#choice30QID404').mouseover(function() { 
$(this).attr('title','You are Hovering'); 
})

$('#choice30QID404').mouseout(function() { 
$(this).removeAttr('title'); 
})
```

This will help you.

Comment: what need jquery to do this?

Comment: Thanks Sathish. It works the way I wanted.
 Can I also apply style to this title text?

Comment: Yes sure. You mean style while hovering right? @Glenn

Comment: Yes Sathish. For example display the 'You are Hovering' in different font, color etc. It that possible too?

Comment: $('#choice30QID404').css('background-color', 'yellow');    Simply!! @Glenn

Comment: no this is not working. basically I am programming on a survey platform.

Comment: title can also add from html there is no need to do jquery

Comment: No issues. Copy & Paste your html. will solve you. @Glenn

Comment: the html is generated on the fly.As i said I am programming on a survey engine. All I have is a question id with which I can only play around with  javascript/jquery.

Comment: For example : <div id="choice30QID404">Text</div>  If this is the Structure. Then surely this will work. $('#choice30QID404').css('propertyname','value');  Check once! Give any one of the css propertyname & value and check.  @Glenn

Comment: @Sathish, I only want to change the font and color of text appearing on hover. not the content of div id

Comment: If that too not working! Then try this $('#choice30QID404').attr('style','background-color : yellow'); @Glenn

Comment: Oops, I'm sorry that's not possible here. Then we should go for our very own customized tooltip. Thank you Glenn. Surely will reach you out! @Glenn

Comment: how can i create that customized tool tip?

Answer (score 0):

You have appended DOM children to your element with the `id` of `choice30QID404`.  You can then remove it on a `.mouseout()` event ([reference](https://api.jquery.com/mouseout/)).
JQuery helps with `.children().remove()`.

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
var $choice = $j("#choice30QID404");

$choice.hover(function () {
  $j(this).append("<span>HOVERING!!!!!</span>");
});              

$choice.click(function() {
  $j(this).mouseout();
});

$choice.mouseout(function() {
  $j(this).children().remove();
});
```

I hope this helps,

Rhys

Comment: on applying your code the content of id also disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this.

Try this

**Script**

```
  var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

  $j("#choice30QID404").hover(
  function () {
     // $j(this).append($("<span> HOVERING!!!!! </span>"));
      $j(this).append("<span class='span1'>HOVERING!!!!!</span>");    
  });              

  $j("#choice30QID404").mouseout(function() {
    $j(this).find('.span1').remove();
  });
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="choice30QID404">
Hover on this
</div>
```

[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lkx4hgt6/2/)

Comment: on applying your code the content of id also disappeared.

Comment: which content of Id?? it just `add/remove` span from `div`.

Comment: the "#choice30QID404" is a label displaying something.

Comment: then you should give a class for hovering span. check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try This -->

You can append a  on mouse hover and on mouseout remove that

```js
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j("#choice30QID404").hover(
  function() {
    // $j(this).append($("<span class='prepended'> HOVERING!!!!! </span>"));
    $j(this).append("<span class='hovering'>HOVERING!!!!!</span>");
  });

$j("#choice30QID404").mouseout(function() {
 // $j(this).mouseout();
  $j(".hovering").remove();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="choice30QID404">Hello<a>
```